# Extracting Values from Json Array and Removing ID Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a Json array.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "data1": "A",
        "data2": "B",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "data1": "C",
        "data2": "D",
    }
]
```

I want to extract only the values and remove the `ID` key then add every object to new nested array like this;

```
[
    [
        "A",
        "B"
    ],
    [
        "C",
        "D"
    ]
]
```

I tried `Object.entries` but this way cannot get rid of the `keys`.

How can I extract only the values without `ID` key and create new array?

I will use this in `filefy`.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you tried

Comment: @Sebastian - You are the master of duplicate originals, nice one!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Found via Google: “site:stackoverflow.com js get values from array of object”.

Comment: `const result = yourArray.map(({ data1, data2 }) => [ data1, data2 ]);`.